# GraphQLError [Object]: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character ";"

Tags: javascript, graphql, express-graphql

While I was setting the server, connecting to the MongoDB database, and doing a mutation, I'm getting the following error after running node index in my terminal: GraphQLError [Object]: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character ";".

Index.JS:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server'); 
const gql = require('graphql-tag'); 


const typeDefs = gql`; 
type Query{ 
    SayHi: String! 
    } 
`; 

const resolvers = { 
    Query: { 
        sayHi: () => 'Hello World!' 

        }
    }; 
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    typeDefs, 
    resolvers 
}); 

server.listen({ port: 5000 }).then((res) => { 
    console.log('Server running at ${res.url}');
})
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `const typeDefs = gql`; ` on line 4?

Comment: For some reason, I still haven't gotten the host after changing the line you said. I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined" when I type node index in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and the error message says exactly what is going wrong. There shouldn't contain `;` in the `gql` block. I resolved the issue by removing the `;` character.